# How can I draw the arrow in this icon?

Tags: sketch-app, icon

How do I draw that arrow? I use scissors to cut out parts of the path but the end became pointy.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator add an Arrowhead via the Stroke options palette (choose the More Options from the palette options in the upper right corner if you don't see the same options below.

[image: Stroke Arrowhead]

Go to the Object Menu and choose Expand Appearance. This will turn the arrow head into an editable vector path. Optionally you can go to Object Menu -> Path -> Outline Stroke. This option is good if you are 100% happy with your stroke width – the first option retains the ability to alter the stroke width.

Press the <kbd>-</kbd> key (or hold down on the Pen tool to get the Delete Anchor Point Tool) and click on the point of the arrow indicated below:

[image]

The arrowhead will now look like this:

[image]

Ungroup your line and arrow head and move the arrowhead in line with your stroke object:

[image]

And viola:

[image]

Obviously that shape isn't exact to your example but since you indicated using the Scissors tool you seem to know how to the start this.

Answer (score 0):

For myself, I would draw the arrow shape directly using the insert>vector command, use not the stroke but the fill, and create a symbol of the finished arrow. I'd put in the text, rotate a copy of the arrow, then save those all grouped as another symbol (with the original arrow symbol nested inside) and that way it's all easily editable later if needed.